# ASP.NET GridView pagination without postback

Tags: asp.net, gridview, asp.net-ajax, modalpopupextender

Just a quick question for all of you guys.

I have a Grid View inside Update Panel. My Modal PopUp pulls this Panel up. I am good so far.

However when I try to do pagination on the popped up grid view, The page Posts Back.

Then the Modal PopUp disappears and so does my GridView.

When I click on mybutton again, It shows the Modal PopUp with Grid View and the Next Page Contents in Grid View.

Is there any way I can get this Grid View to do pagination without Postback and without losing Modal PopUp ?

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

The page must post back each time you change the page of the GridView.  However, you can emulate the desired functionality by hooking into the PageIndexChanged event of the GridView:

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    modalPopupExtender1.Show();
}
```

Comment: Voted your solution UP.. You saved me.. I thought I knew everything about AJAX. But not... Thank you guy

Answer (score 0):

You should have this layout:

```
<ModalPopup>
   <UpdatePanel>
       <GridView>
   <UpdatePanel>
</ModalPopup>
```

That way your ModalPopup won't disappear, **unless** you have another an outer updatepanel, and that updatepanel is set to UpdateMode=Always

Comment: I have ModalPopUpExtender and I do not see any UpdatePanel inside it. What I have is as follows: 

<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" > ....</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender> 

<asp:Panel ID="PolicyEffectedPanel" runat="server" Style="display: none" CssClass="modalPopup"> 

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updtpnlBoard" runat="server" > 
<ContentTemplate> 

<asp:GridView ID="pnlPoliciesGridView" runat="server"> </asp:GridView> 
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel> 

Any suggestions ??

Comment: That looks correct. Do you have another update panel that is a parent of your modal popup?

Answer (score 0):

the popup should only dissappear when CancelControlID/OkControlID are clicked. More than 1 update panels can be a bit trickier.

Are you handling the page change event.

```
Private Sub Grid_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles Grid.PageIndexChanging
    Grid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    Grid.SelectedIndex = -1
    Grid.DataBind()
End Sub
```

This is not important ( from the point of this question), but your change you updateMode to Conditional.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is helpful to someone, Matthew Jones [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1724971/5342284) worked for me, If you have grid view inside user control and the parent aspx page has the `ModalPopupExtender` use `OnPageIndexChanged` of the grid view

```
protected void gvAccountSearch_PageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var popup = Parent.FindControl("mdlAccount") as ModalPopupExtender;
        if (popup != null)
            popup.Show();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```